# Enable APE( Monkey's audo) decoder in FFmpeg configure

Tags: ffmpeg, decoder

I have disabled all the decoders ,encoders and demuxers using the command **--disable-decoders** , **--disable-encoders** and **--disable-demuxers** in FFmpeg, now I want to selectively enable them for the formats that I wish to use,I have done this for some of the formats eg.for OGG- **--enable-decoder=vorbis** and **--enable-demuxer=ogg** ,so which command will enable the decoder and demuxer for **APE(Monkey's Audio)**.

Answer (score 1):

Codec and demuxer called "ape".
Try `--enable-demuxer=ape --enable-decoder=ape`